# How to make the scrollbar for an output cell visible on Safari?

Tags: css, safari, jupyter-notebook

[image]I want to display long rows in a output cell of Jupiter notebook. I have customised the css and got it properly displayed in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari it does not work.

I want to disable all inner scrollbars and enable just one outer scrollbar (please see the attached image). For that purpose, i used "overflow: hidden" for "pre {}", and added "overflow: scroll" for ".output{}". After that I can see the "bar" under the output cell but not the "scroll" one.

```
pre {
.....
overflow: hidden;
}

.output {
.....
overflow: scroll;
}
```

I expect that the outer scrollbar should look like the inner one.

Comment: pls share html and css

Comment: Sorry, the whole html and css is so long, i don't know how can share it here. It is simple the Jupyter notebook interface, if you are familiar with it. Actually we have the work with only pre{} and .output{} i talked above. And from the picture above, you can also see the elements structure. Thank you.

Comment: your code is correct.. but scroll bar you should darg its move automatically.

Comment: sorry, what does it mean? i should change to "overflow: auto;" ? i tried but it did not work.

Comment: yes.. you should add overflow auto